# Create a new Shape from the value of String.valueOf(Object obj)

Tags: java, string, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to create a new `Shape` instance from given `String`, which is e.g. a value returned by `String.valueOf(Object obj)` static method for the `Shape` parameter. Let's say I created a `Circle` and I've added few additional features to it:

```
Circle circle = new Circle(10, 10, 10, Color.BLACK);
circle.setStroke(Color.RED);
circle.setStrokeWidth(2);
```

Now, I'm writing the value returned by `String.valueOf(circle)`, which is:

```
Circle[centerX=10.0, centerY=10.0, radius=10.0, 
fill=0x000000ff, stroke=0xff0000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]
```

...in a `*.txt` file, or something similar to that. Next, I read this `*.txt` file and I put it's content in a new `String`, say:

```
String stringCircle = "Circle[centerX=10.0, centerY=10.0, radius=10.0, "
                + "fill=0x000000ff, stroke=0xff0000ff, strokeWidth=2.0]";
```

What would be the best approach to create a new `Circle` instance from `stringCircle` value?

Answer (score 2):

Consider overriding the `toString` method of Circle to return an easily readable string of values, and then writing the constructor, `public Circle(String definition)` to read that String accordingly.

The string could be something like `10.0 10.0 10.0 0x000000ff 0xff0000ff 2.0`
Since you've implemented the toString and the constructor, you can assume the parameter order is always the same and then use a string tokenizer with a space as the delimiter to easily assign the values.

Comment: +1 It seem to be one of the possible pretty efficient approaches for this issue. But I'm still looking.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab each value just by parsing the stringCircle string, something like this:

```
int newStart = stringCircle.indexOf(",");
double centerX = Double.parseDouble(stringCircle.substring(stringCircle.indexOf("=") + 1, newStart));
stringCircle = stringCircle.substring(newStart + 1);

newStart = stringCircle.indexOf(",");
double centerY = Double.parseDouble(stringCircle.substring(stringCircle.indexOf("=") + 1, newStart));
stringCircle = stringCircle.substring(newStart + 1);
//...
newStart = stringCircle.indexOf(",");
int stroke = Integer.parseInt(stringCircle.substring(stringCircle.indexOf("=") + 1, newStart));
stringCircle = stringCircle.substring(newStart + 1);
//...
```

and then pass them as you need, to constructors and suchlike. This could be done in a loop as well, if you put the parsed results into an array for example.